# Collection View overlaps above when scrolling vertically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I have collectionView but above that a UIView as well. When I scroll my collectionView vertically and go up, it scrolls and overlaps the UIView. 
What could be the solution to make the UIView come on top of collectionView?

What did work was turning off clips to bounds in the collection View from storyboard.

Comment: Not getting your question properly!

Comment: The collection view when scrolls, it comes over on top of another view rather going under it.

Comment: Are you using autolayout ? It may be the issue of wrong constraints! Hows you setup your UIs ? Your collectionview and that view both are in common superview ?

Comment: Yeah, they are in same superview. Checked constraints once again, they seem alright.

Comment: show your constraints for both in question!

Comment: Yeah added a picture

Comment: have you checked my answer?

Comment: issue resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Set the property "Clip to Bounds" to true. It can be done programatically or in the auto layout.

Programatically: colelctionView.clipToBounds = true

Auto Layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints should be like,

`View` - `top,leading,trailing and fixed height`

`collection view` - `top,leading,trailing,bottom`

and after that setup, you got issue then once try to set below in `viewDidload`,

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: Tried this but didn't work.
I created a demo project, their it seems to work fine

Comment: I think the same, auto insets might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping View Below the Collection View in the View Hierarchy.

[image: Storyboard Hierarchy]

This looks sneaky, what let us know the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just play with the Section Inset

[image]